# How to tell if an attribute call is originated from Controller vs. Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

When an action filter is called, is there any way to determine whether this call is originated from an attribute applied at controller level or action level?

I need myAttribute to be run for all of my action methods. The Delete action method, however, is specifically annotated with the filter so myAttribute is called twice. I need the call originated from Controller to do nothing or potentially do different things in that case.

Is there anyway to do this without actually removing the [myAttribute] from controller?

```
[myAttribute]
public class HomeController
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
    }

    public ViewResult View()
    {
    }

    public ViewResult Edit()
    {
    }

    [myAttribute]
    public ViewResult Delete()
    {

    }
}
```

I am using these action filters to authorize a user. A user could have access to a controller but if a method specifically demands permission (by having [myAttribute] above it), then controller level access is not enough and that action should be explicitly mentioned in user permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution,
What you need to understand is Attributes is designed to use for `Annotation` only not to define `Behavior`.
Moreover, When you apply Filter attribute on a Controller, It actually meant to apply for all the `ActionMethods` within the controller.

What I suggest is, Create one more `FilterAttribute` that have specific work related to your Delete method and decorate your method with it.